# Assigning and method call order

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, call, normalize

I wrote such a property (representing direction for my XNA game object):

```cs
public Vector2 Direction
{
    get { return direction; }
    protected set
    {
        (direction = value).Normalize(); // ***
        angle = MathHelper.WrapAngle((float)Math.Atan(direction.X / direction.Y));
    }
}
```

**set** sets two equivalent fields which represent object's orientation in angle and simultaneously in normalized vector.

Starting game failed because line marked by ******* failed. It doesn't normalize vector.
I changed this line to:

```cs
direction = value;
direction.Normalize();
```

and it works fine... Why?
I assumed that in line marked by ******* first operation is assigning **value** and then normalising **direction**. But it's not true.


***_*__**     **__*_***     ***_*___**

**Normalize()** is method from **Vector2** class.

```cs
//
// Summary:
//     Turns the current vector into a unit vector. The result is a vector one unit
//     in length pointing in the same direction as the original vector.
public void Normalize();
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're talking about.

Comment: Please include the exception that is getting thrown / the error message causing your game to fail.

Comment: By "game failing" I meant that game's logic wasn't updated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming Vector2 is a struct, or value type, which means it is passed-by-value and not by reference. When you assign value to direction, you are setting direction to a copy of value. Additionally, the object returned by the expression (direction = value) is a copy, and not the same instance that is in direction. You are calling Normalize on an object that is never stored outside of the setter block.

For this same reason you cannot call methods or set properties on a struct returned from a property getter on a class. For instance, if the property from your example is in a class named Monkey, note:

```
Monkey m = new Monkey();
m.Direction = new Vector2(...);
m.Direction.X = 2; // This will not compile.
m.Direction.Normalize(); // This will not do what you expect.
```